# Highcharts : Point Formatting not working

Tags: highcharts, formatting

I have a Highcharts graph similar to the this (http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/area-stacked-percent/).

The only part I have not been able to get working is formatting the percentage values that appear on the tooltip. If I put the below code then the percentage value shows up but it has too many decimal places...

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage}%</b><br/>',
    shared: true
}
```

But if I have I tried to format the value of point.percentage to show less decimal places like so...

```
{ point.percentage:.1f }%
```

then only the literal "{point.percentage:.1f}%" shows up in the graph tooltip.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what could be wrong? Is there any other way to format that percentage value other than the above?

Thanks.

Comment: question contradicts with explanation; it suppose to be tool tip formatting!

Comment: I had the same problem and made it work by setting the tooltip options for each series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use tooltip [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and use [Highcharts.numberFormat()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat)

Comment: Hi Sebastian, may I trouble you for the actual code. I tried the below and it gave the error "ReferenceError: point is not defined"...  tooltip: {
                      formatter: function() {
                     
                     return '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b> ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.percentage, 2)  +' %</b><br/>';
                    }

Comment: sorry for the multiple edits, hope you did not get too many notifications, I was not sure how to put code into comments. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Use this consturicon var points = this.point in the top of formatter.

Comment: You mean something like what is in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jjaleel/qChtL/2/ , still does not work for me.

Comment: I advice to use console in developers tools (Firefox / Chrome), then you will notice that you have shared tooltip and point is not availabe, only array of points. In case hwen you need single point, then point will work. (shared paramt should be commented then). http://jsfiddle.net/qChtL/3/

Comment: It works perfectly now http://jsfiddle.net/jjaleel/qChtL/4/, thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the approach is working, according to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ethanph5/VSKx3/

The snippet you are interested:

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b><br/>',
    shared: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ethan, but for some reason the ":.1f" notation does not work in my application, although it works in a fiddle. That is why I went with the approach Sebastian suggested.